# Squeryl and PostgreSQL's autoincrement

Tags: postgresql, squeryl

When I try to insert a new record in a PostgreSQL table using Squeryl's Table.insert, it fires this query:

```
insert into "users" ("id", "email", "fullname") values (nextval('"s_users_id"'),?,?)
```

This doesn't work, as I did not define a sequence and instead defined the id column to be "autoincrement":

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id BIGSERIAL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    fullname varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I read some old post in another forum about this issue, and I was wondering what the status is now. Are we discouraged to use autoincrement and define a sequence instead? Or is there a simple workaround to get this working?

Edit: In fact just now I see that the autoincrement itself creates a serial, but under another name: users_id_seq Is there a way to tell Squeryl to look under this name instead, or follow PostgreSQL's convention?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can declare name of the sequence:

```
 case class Author(id: Long, firstName: String)             

 val author = table[Author]

 on(author)(s => declare(
    s.id is(autoIncremented("your_seq_name"))
 ))
```

more information: http://squeryl.org/schema-definition.html

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a terribly clean way to do it right now, but it can be done.  Just subclass PostgreSqlAdapter and override:

`def createSequenceName(fmd: FieldMetaData)`

Answer (score 3):

`serial` or `bigserial` **will** create a sequence in the background from which the values for the column are taken. So the insert is basically correct.

`bigserial` is just a shorthand for:

```
create sequence users_id_seq;
create table users (id bigint default nextval('users_id_seq'));
```

The only thing that seems wrong is that default name of the sequence for your id column would be `users_id_seq`, not `s_users_id` as used by your tool.

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

**Edit**:
One possible workaround if that tool assumes the wrong naming convention is to rename the generated sequence. As Postgres "knows" it belongs to the column things will still work.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RENAME TO s_users_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, you are really fast. I just realized the same thing when looking again. So then it would be a question if Squeryl can be modified to look up the sequence under the default name when in PostgreSQL mode.

Comment: @JeroenKransen: sorry I don't know Squeryl. As a workaround you could just rename the sequence PostgreSQL created.